# The electrical outlet for my garbage disposal suddenly started running hot all the time

Tags: electrical

One day a few weeks ago, my switch controlled garbage disposal just turned on, and would not turn off until I unplugged the power cord. Now the only way to operate the disposal is by plugging and unplugging it.
The outlet it is plugged into is a double switch, and the other switch still powers the lights above my sink. They still work properly.
Any ideas? Do I have a loose wire at the outlet making my disposal connection hot all the time?

Answer (score 4):

The logical answer is the switch failed. Turn off the power to the switch. Remove one wire. Isolate it so it doesn't touch anything . Restore the power and plug in the disposal. If it doesn't run, you know you have to replace the switch. If it does still run, you have to get into the outlet box. The outlet or associated wiring is the issue.

Comment: Yes, the inductive motor will stress the switch. The only household wall switch that I have ever seen fail was on a garbage disposal.